# How to move text component of a multi-step progress "bar" in React using ordered list?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm new to front end development. Working on an application using React and I'm a little stumped on this piece. I'm currently trying to setup a type of status to display to a user. There are three sections - for now we'll just consider them as step1, step2, step3. My goal is to have each of those sections represent a stage in the overall progress that an object on the backend is currently in. All three stages will be displayed on the page, but the colors will change depending on which stage its on. I am trying to avoid using any third party libraries that generate it for me. This is partially an attempt to learn how this works, but I'll happily look into any material someone has that can better explain how to do this.

[illustration of what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbBle.png)

Currently, dark blue means the object is past that stage, light blue means the object is currently on that stage, and grey means the object has not reached that stage yet. I currently have it hard coded to display one of each, but technically the display of this specific code would indicate that the object is on step2 of the process. I know I'll need to dynamically change the colors depending on the stage.

Things I need help with.

1. I want the text to display below it, not inside of it. I'm not sure if I fundamentally need to change the elements used to create it in order for that to work, or if there is an additional element I can put in there or additional styling from css that can move it. I ideally want to have the text line up with the bottom left corner of the "arrow" that's created. I may also have some additional elements embedded in this text such as a link, but I think the emphasis I have is getting it to display in the right spot and I'll worry about adding those properties afterwards.
2. I want this to be useable on a mobile screen and a desktop, but the bar completely breaks if I alter the size of the browser window and begin to make the window smaller than the size of the bar. How should I approach making this scale in size depending on how much space it has?

Here is what I currently have.

ProgressArrow.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "../css/ProgressArrow.css";

const ProgressArrow = () => {


  return (
    <div className="progress-arrow">
        <ol class="steps">
            <li class="step1"><span>Step 1</span></li>
            <li class="step2"><span>Step 2</span></li>
            <li class="step3"><span>Step 3</span></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProgressArrow;
```

ProgressArrow.css

```
ol.steps {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 8px;
    font-weight: bold;
    counter-reset: li;
}
ol.steps li {
    list-style-image: none;
    list-style-type: none;

    text-align: center;
    color: #3a3a3a;
    background: #b6b6b6;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 90px;
    width: 280px;
}
ol.steps li:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 100%;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-left-color: #b6b6b6;
    border-width: 40px;
    margin-top: -40px;
}
ol.steps li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
ol.steps li:first-child span {
    padding: 9px;
}
ol.steps li:first-child span:after {
    border: none;
}
ol.steps li:last-child:after {
    border-width: 0;
}
ol.steps li span {
    display: block;
    padding: 9px 28px 9px 9px;
}
ol.steps li span:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 100%;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    border: solid #b6b6b6;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    border-width: 40px;
    margin-top: -40px;
}

ol.steps > li {
    float: left;
}


ol.steps li.step1 {
    z-index: 3;
    background: #002d62;
    color: white;
}
ol.steps li.step1:after {
    border-left-color: #002d62;
}
ol.steps li.step1 span:after {
    border: solid #002d62;
}
ol.steps li.step2 {
    z-index: 2;
    color: #fff;
    background: #00599c;
}
ol.steps li.step2:after {
    border-left-color: #00599c;
}
ol.steps li.step2 span:after {
    border-color: #00599c;
    border-left-color: transparent;
}
ol.steps li.step3 {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I've considered making a table and having the associated text be the second row of each of these, that way it should line up, but I was having some difficulty translating this into a table and necessarily want to go down the wrong rabbit hole.

As far as scaling the bar depending on the screen size, I know that there is syntax like `@media` and percentage based sizing instead of absolute pixel. But there are several pieces involved with creating those arrow effects and I'm not sure how they all need to scale in relation to each other just yet.